# How can I check how many instances of a Google Cloud Run container are running?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Google Cloud Run lets me set a *concurrency* for a given container, which is how many concurrent requests it will service before a new container is spun up.

How do I actually check how many containers are running at any given time? The web interface mentions which services are running but not how many of them there are, and the same is true when I do `gcloud beta run services (list|describe)`.

Comment: Would the stackdriver logs perhaps be one way to measure this story?

Answer (score 6):

Cloud Run [reports the number of container instances in Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run)

The [Billable instance time](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run) metric counts how many instance time you are charged for. For example, if a Revision with 2 container instances has been continuously serving traffic in the last minute, the value is 2s/s.

Alternatively, you can [export your logs to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/). Each log entry has an instance ID as label (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#log-resource)) that you can group by and count.

Comment: Thanks, @Steren! What about using Google Cloud Run on GKE and just looking at the deployments there through kubectl?

Comment: Correct, for Cloud Run on GKE, you should be able to monitor the number of pods created.

Comment: It would be so much easier if Cloud Run would expose this metric. This was one of the first things I was looking for when I started to test my service, in particular, to understand how autoscaling behaves and the load (# active connections) on the connected Cloud SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

For a more direct metric of the number of Cloud Run instances I propose using the

```
run.googleapis.com/container/instance_count
```

endpoint of the [monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).