# GCP Eventarc & mutiple cloudrun creation -duplicate processing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have following use case while learning GCP cloudrun and concurrency setting

Every 15-30 mins or so , folder will get new multiple large (XXXMb to 1gb)files by external process.
These files needs to read and transform data as per need and store in one table in Bigquery. ( all files data goes to one table) & remove read files from folder.

Evnetarch is used to trigger Cloud run instance on each file creation in Folder.

I m not sure how cloud run instance is managed based on Eventarc and if for any reason there are multiple instances of same cloud run is created & if all instances will get notification for same file.

if so, same file will be processed by 2 instances of same cloud run and resulting duplicate data in Bigquery table.

for this kind of case, does it need to write custom code where each instance store info outside of cloudrun that which file it is processing? like multithreading concept ? or any standard solution for this?

also how to know programmatically (in cloud run -python code) if there are multiple instances are running .

Following image:

[image]

any clarity/solution  on this will be great.

Comment: Can you have a look at this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73235468/18265702) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73074505/18265702).

Comment: Are your main problem is the multiple Cloud Run trigger on the same file? If so, can you share how long the file processing take?

Comment: I have not yet fully implemented yet.This is my proactive query if eventarc notification underlying logic trigger 2 instance of cloud run and notify about file creation ,both will have notifciaiton of same file and process it.

Comment: Have a look at this [Stack overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912701/18265702) to check the number of instances running.